# Android set() and setExact() alarms firing at incorrect intervals

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm developing an app that should perform a certain task every 60 seconds. Since there's some accuracy problems with alarms in Android 4.4+, where all alarms are inexact, I've opted for the chained model: A `BroadcastReceiver` fires the first alarm, and each alarm in turn sets the next alarm.

The problem is that, even though I'm setting the alarms at intervals of 60 seconds (60000 ms), the alarms trigger at 5 second intervals, and sometimes even less. I've tested the code on my Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1) and on an Android 5.0.1 emulator, both giving the same result.
I should point out that both receivers are registered on the AndroidManifest and my application has the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.

EDIT: setExact() causes exactly the same problem

**StartupReceiver.java** (BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED):

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got the BOOT_COMPLETED signal");
        // Get the first alarm to be invoked immediately
        AlarmReceiver.setNextScanAlarm(context, 0);
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Start the service
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        startServiceIntent.putExtra("interval", 60000);
        startServiceIntent.putExtra("action", "scan");
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);

        // Schedule the next alarm
        setNextScanAlarm(context, 60000);
    }

    public static void setNextScanAlarm(Context context, int interval) {
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        scanIntent.putExtra("interval", interval);
        scanIntent.putExtra("action", "scan");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                scanIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                interval,
                pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just a quick question are you actually doing anything with alarms or just trying to run some code in the background or main UI every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I believe because this is an alarm clock when calling

```
alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                interval,
                pendingIntent);
```

The variable you are calling `interval` is the amount of time you want to elapse UNTIL the next alarm , but when you think about this when does it know to start? More so, when does time actually equal zero?
 
When you create it? No. 
When you call `.set()`? No.
 
It is actually zero upon BOOT. So you are asking it to launch 60 seconds after boot, and your asking for this everytime, this time will have already elapsed.

This is where the confusion is, and where you should probably just use a call like `new 
Handler.postDelayed(Runnnable r, 60000)` instead of an alarm Manager. It will be much more accurate and will not be subject to some problems with understanding the Android Operating System and its alarms/clocks/etc/etc.

But for your specific case I believe you could solve it by accessing `System` function calls/variables. So inside of your function `setNextScanAlarm()` I believe it would look like this:

```
   public static void setNextScanAlarm(Context context, int interval) {
        //create the intent the same way as before
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        scanIntent.putExtra("interval", interval);
        scanIntent.putExtra("action", "scan");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                scanIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //create new variables to calculate the correct time for this to go off
        long timeRightNow = System.elapsedRealTime() //use something else if you change AlarmManager type
        long timeWhenIShouldGoOff = timeRightNow + interval;

        //use the new timeWhenIShouldGoOff variable instead of interval
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                timeWhenIShouldGoOff,
                pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35454203/4527678) to a similar question.
I use `postDelayed()` instead of `AlarmManager` for the short time intervals (less than 1 minute), and `AlarmManager` for long.